# Specify starcluster sshmaster port

Tags: starcluster

When using starcluster, is it possible to specify the port number when SSHing into the master node? For example:

```
starcluster sshmaster mycluster --port 22
```

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible to define the port number to use when connecting to master with "sshmaster". Here is the output of the "help" command over sshmaster.

```
%> starcluster sshmaster -h
StarCluster - (http://star.mit.edu/cluster) (v. 0.9999)
Software Tools for Academics and Researchers (STAR)
Please submit bug reports to starcluster@mit.edu

Usage: sshmaster [options] <cluster> [<remote-command>]

    SSH to a cluster's master node

    Example:

        $ sshmaster mycluster

    You can also execute commands without directly logging in:

        $ starcluster sshmaster mycluster 'cat /etc/hosts'

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -u USER, --user=USER  login as USER (defaults to root)
  -X, --forward-x11     enable X11 forwarding
  -A, --forward-agent   enable authentication agent forwarding
  -t, --pseudo-tty      enable pseudo-tty allocation (for interactive commands
                    and screens)
```